# Using Services.AddAuthentication() causes application to stop on startup

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, dpapi

In a basic Asp Net Core web API project ( `dotnet new webapi`, SDK 7.0 ) adding an authentication handler via

```csharp
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>(
            BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, null);
```

causes the application to exit before completing the startup. Enabling verbose logging it's possible to notice that, when the call to `app.Run()` is performed, it uses DPAPI to decrypt a key and it suddenly stops with no exception nor log of any kind, neither in Windows' registry.

```
[System         ][DBUG][23-11-17T14:27:54.9231+01:00][0][        Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host]`Hosting starting`
[System         ][INFO][23-11-17T14:27:55.4962+01:00][0][NetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager]`User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\p.dicaprio.extblar\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.`
[System         ][DBUG][23-11-17T14:27:55.5027+01:00][0][ataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository]`Reading data from file 'C:\Users\p.dicaprio.extblar\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys\key-70202a7b-a057-403b-b974-5060170571f3.xml'.`
[System         ][DBUG][23-11-17T14:27:55.5232+01:00][0][NetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager]`Found key {70202a7b-a057-403b-b974-5060170571f3}.`
[System         ][DBUG][23-11-17T14:27:55.5363+01:00][0][re.DataProtection.KeyManagement.DefaultKeyResolver]`Considering key {70202a7b-a057-403b-b974-5060170571f3} with expiration date 2024-02-15 13:20:05Z as default key.`
[System         ][DBUG][23-11-17T14:27:55.5390+01:00][0][.AspNetCore.DataProtection.TypeForwardingActivator]`Forwarded activator type request from Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 to Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60`
[System         ][DBUG][23-11-17T14:27:55.5429+01:00][0][ore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor]`Decrypting secret element using Windows DPAPI.`
```

`BasicAuthenticationHandler` is's very simple: it reads the Authorization header, removes `Basic:`  from it and decodes the base64 credentials provided to check if in a `Dictionary<string,string>` exists a valid key/value pair.

Any suggestion on what to verify?

P.S.
It works on my machine, it works on a server A, it shows this problem on a server B (totally out of my control).
The `app.Run()` is surrounded by a try/catch(Exception) but no log is provided by the catch.

**SOLVED**

I asked to the server B provider to add an exclusion for my program's folder in Sophos antivirus and now the program runs as expected.

The log does not stop to `Decrypting secret element using Windows DPAPI.` but continues as:

```
[System         ][DBUG][23-11-21T07:07:43.1380+01:00][0][ore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor]`Decrypting secret element using Windows DPAPI.`
[System         ][DBUG][23-11-21T07:07:43.1733+01:00][0][.AspNetCore.DataProtection.TypeForwardingActivator]`Forwarded activator type request from Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.ConfigurationModel.AuthenticatedEncryptorDescriptorDeserializer, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 to Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.ConfigurationModel.AuthenticatedEncryptorDescriptorDeserializer, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60`
[System         ][DBUG][23-11-21T07:07:43.1828+01:00][0][atedEncryption.CngCbcAuthenticatedEncryptorFactory]`Opening CNG algorithm 'AES' from provider 'null' with chaining mode CBC.`
[System         ][DBUG][23-11-21T07:07:43.1842+01:00][0][atedEncryption.CngCbcAuthenticatedEncryptorFactory]`Opening CNG algorithm 'SHA256' from provider 'null' with HMAC.`
[System         ][DBUG][23-11-21T07:07:43.1857+01:00][0][tCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider]`Using key {70202a7b-a057-403b-b974-5060170571f3} as the default key.`
[System         ][DBUG][23-11-21T07:07:43.1890+01:00][0][ataProtection.Internal.DataProtectionHostedService]`Key ring with default key {70202a7b-a057-403b-b974-5060170571f3} was loaded during application startup.`
[System         ][INFO][23-11-21T07:07:43.3196+01:00][0][                        Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime]`Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

Probably an antivirus rule was blocking the decryption of the key.

Comment: Try checking in the "Exception settings" the "Common Language Runtime Exception" and see what is the actual exception is. Also, it may be Permission issue.

Comment: I just added a P.S. section: I'm not connected with a debugger and I doing so is not an option. The issue appears only on a 3rd party server, not on my machine with the debugger and not on my server where I run the build output.

Comment: You must have made sure that DPAPI config on both the server A and B is same and there is no difference between.

Comment: On server A no configuration has been performed. For server B I have no data. Could you suggest me what to check? Maybe link some resource?

Comment: could you check and compare both server .NET SDK versions, installed runtime libraries, security policies, and user permissions. check if there are any issues with DPAPI on Server B. try adding a global exception handler to catch and log any unhandled exceptions. if you still not able to catch the exception you could try using the debugging tools to attach to the process on Server B to get more detailed information about what's happening at the moment the application stops. Check if the file system permissions on Server B allow the application to access the `DataProtection-Keys` directory.

Comment: Just edited the post, it was Sophos blocking the key decryption without raising alarms